# Rails how to build on iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

After trying to save a set of images with dropzone without iteration. i switch to iterating the images and try to save on the loop. but rails spitting

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /products
>   =========================================== > SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   images.product_id: INSERT INTO "images" ("created_at", "ifoto",
>   "product_data_id", "product_id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
>   app/controllers/products_controller.rb, line 214
>   ------------------------------------------------ `ruby 209 210 if params[:images] && params[:images][:ifoto] 211
>   params[:images][:ifoto].values.each do |ifoto| 212 213 @image.ifoto =
>   ifoto > 214 @image.save 215 216 217 end 218 render :nothing => true
>   219` App backtrace ------------- -
>   app/controllers/products_controller.rb:214:in `block (3 levels) in
>   create' - app/controllers/products_controller.rb:211:in`block (2
>   levels) in create' - app/controllers/products_controller.rb:137:in
>   `create' Full backtrace --

here is the dropzone code

```
 format.json do
     @product = current_vitrine.products.build(params[:product])
        @image =  @product.images.build(params[:images])



if params[:images] && params[:images][:ifoto]
       params[:images][:ifoto].values.each do |ifoto|

@image.ifoto = ifoto
  @image.save


                    end
    render :nothing => true

    end
  end
```

someone have a hint to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks information about models and relations.
With so little knowledge I am only guessing.
Try this:

```
@product = current_vitrine.products.build(params[:product])

if @product.save
  if params[:images] && params[:images][:ifoto]
    params[:images][:ifoto].values.each do |ifoto|
      @product.images.create(ifoto: ifoto)
    end
  end
end

format.json { render :nothing => true }
```